# Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall - Error when trying to verify ISBN

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I'm trying to verify ISBN numbers in C but when I run the program I get the following error: Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall

This is for a homework assignment in a CS class.  I've done all the work so it's not like I'm asking people to do my assignment for me.  I'm just wondering why I'm getting this error as I'm new to the C language; I come from a Java background as well as some web programming languages.  Anyways, here's the assignment description if it'll help:

Perform a check on the characters in an ISBN to verify correctness.

The check character is computed as follows: 
First, compute the sum of the first digit plus two times the second digit 
plus three times the third digit, ... , plus nine times the ninth digit. The 
last character is the remainder when the sum is divided by 11.  If the 
remainder is 10, the last character is X. For example, the sum for 
the ISBN 0-8065-0959-7 is

1*0 + 2*8 + 3*0 + 4*6 + 5*5 + 6*0 + 7*9 + 8*5 + 9*9 = 249

The remainder when 249 is divided by 11 is 7, the last character in the ISBN. 
The check character is used to validate an ISBN.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkISBN( char[] );  
#define size 18L
int main() {
int i,j;
char* s[size] = {
            "0-8065-0959-7",
            "0-534-37964-8", 
            "0-618-50298-X",
            "0-8065-0959-8", 
            "0-534-37964-9", 
            "0-618-50298-5",
            "0-534-37964-8", 
            "0-618-50298-X",            
            "032121353X",
            "0321199553",
            "0201794896",
            "0870495275",
            "0452264464", 
            "0536901562",
            "158901104X",  
            "080801076X",
            "80-902734-1-6"
            "158901104X" };


for( i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if( checkISBN( s[i] ) == 1 )
        printf("%-15s is a valid ISBN \n",s[i]);
    else
        printf("%-15s is NOT a valid ISBN*****\n",s[i]);
}

putchar('\n'); //write a newline
system("pause");`enter code here`
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



int checkISBN( char s[] ) 
{


int result = 0;
    int i;
int n = 1;
int sum = 0;
char ch[10];
    int final[10];
    int sizeOfArray = strlen(s);


for(i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++){
if(s[i] == '-'){
++i;}
if(s[strlen(s)-1] == 'X'){
s[strlen(s)-1] = 10;}
ch[i] = s[i];
}

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
final[i] = atoi(&ch[i]);}

for(i=0; i<9; i++){
sum+= final[i]*n;
++n;}


int checkCharacter = sum%11;

if(checkCharacter == final[9]){
result = 1;}
  return result;}
```

Comment: Er, why are you using `system()`? If you really want to wait for a keypress just use `getchar()`. Secondly, have a think about why `ch[i] = s[i]` is wrong - what happens when `sizeOfArray` > 10? (hint, this is a stack corruption crash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <ctype.h>

int checkISBN( char s[] ) {
    int i, n = 1, sum = 0, checksum;

    for(i=0; s[i]; ++i){
        if(s[i] == '-')
            continue;
        if(n<10 && isdigit(s[i]))
            sum += n++*(s[i] - '0');
        else if(n==10){
            if(s[i] == 'X')
                checksum = 10;
            else if(isdigit(s[i]))
                checksum = s[i] - '0';
        }
    }
    return sum % 11 == checksum;
}
```

also

```
"80-902734-1-6", //need comma
```

Comment: Needs to be checked form more strictly.